# LWJGL Applet Security Exception

Tags: java, lwjgl

I created small game in Java using LWJGL 2.9.3 and would like to add it to webpage as Java applet. I have followed [this](http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet) tutorial and have used [this](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/applet/advance/appletloader.html) app loader. All the Java code works and I can tun the applet in my IDE. However, when I try to run the applet in a webpage I get the following error:

> SercurityException
>
> attempted to open sandboxed jar http:// 127.0.0.1/lwjgl_util_applet.jar as Trusted-Libary

Any idea what is wrong and how may I fix it?

Comment: Don't even bother trying to use Java applets in 2015; Oracle have deliberately made them very hard to use.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to use then for a web based LWJGL project then?

Comment: My suggestion is don't. Web-based Java is dead, unfortunately. About the only alternative seems to be JavaScript, which is a horrible language. Or you could make a downloadable JAR file.